# laravel why the session returns null?

Tags: laravel, session

```
Route::get("test", function (){
    $result = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get("filter_values");

    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::forget("filter_values");
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::put('filter_values', "abcdef");

    dd("result: ", $result);
});
```

Why the session return null when the page is refreshed ?

Comment: Running `dd()` generally prevents things from being set to session, as it kills all subsequent execution, including the logic to persist to session handler. Use `\Log::info(session()->get('filter_values'))` instead and check `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for `'abcdef'`

Comment: @Tim Lewis same result returns null

Comment: Of course it returns `null`; if you followed my comment, you removed the `dd()` function. Did you check your logs as I instructed? Your code works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nTdx.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/42UUs.png

Comment: If you use the get() method after the put() method, it also works with the dd() function.If you look at the example above, I am using a variable after the put() method

Comment: It still works if you do `$result = session()->get("filter_values");`, then `Log::info($result)`, **but only after the first reload.** On initial visit, i.e. before `session()->put()` has been run, it logs `''` blank. All subsequent refreshes log `'abcdef'`, so still working as intended. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7x8P.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq8Xg.png

Comment: Also, **stop using `dd()`**; I've already said it prevents `session()->put()` from saving the value to the session. If the request lifecycle doesn't finish, which it won't when `dd()` is run, you'll never be able to save that value to session.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::forget("filter_values");
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::put('filter_values', "abcdef");
$result = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get("filter_values");
dd($result);
```

You declaring a variable with blank session at the start and assigning value to the session after that.

After changing. You have to run the command to clear the cache.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: so, why is it returning null when the page is refreshed

Comment: because when you defined the result variable by getting the session. The session doesn't have value.

Comment: It returns null the first time, I agree on this point. but then I wonder how it returns null. Is there a value in session?

Comment: No offence but you have to learn that mate. I'm not gone teach you how it works.